# Closest matrix with specific eigenvector

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

Consider a vector ${\bf x}$ and a matrix $A_0$ with $A_0(i,j)\ge 0$. What is the best way of getting matrix $A$ s.t.

$$A = \arg \min \|A-A_0\|_{\text F}$$

subject to

$$A{\bf x} = \lambda {\bf x} \hspace{2mm} \mbox{and} \hspace{2mm} A(i,j)\ge0$$

where $\|\cdot\|_{\text F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm?

Comment: You can use `\le` to write $\le$ and `\ge` for $\ge$.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ fixed?

Comment: Haha, I thought something looked wrong! Thanks

Comment: @MichaelGrant no $\lambda$ is not fixed

Comment: May I assume by $A(i,j)\geq 0$ you mean that the matrix is elementwise nonnegative?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you what your application is? The convex optimization community is always interested to know of new potential applications.

Comment: Hi Michael, it is to do with smoothing observations in training sets as a pre-processing step for classification learning algorithms (in particular neural networks). I'm happy to go into more detail if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matrix structure hides the fact that this is a relatively simple convex optimization problem. Let $\mathop{\textbf{vec}}$ be the operator that "stacks" the columns of a matrix into a tall vector. Then this problem is

\begin{array}{ll}
   \text{minimize}_{a,\lambda}   & \| a - a_0 \|_2 \\
   \text{subject to} & (x^T \otimes I) a - \lambda x = 0 \\
                     & a \geq 0
\end{array}
where $a \triangleq \mathop{\textbf{vec}}(A)$ and $a_0 \triangleq \mathop{\textbf{vec}}(A_0)$, and $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations).
This is easily cast as either a [second-order cone program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming) or a [quadratic program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming). The objective function is convex in $A$, and the constraints are linear in $(A,\lambda)$.

If you use a modeling framework like [CVX](http://cvxr.com) (disclaimer: mine) or [YALMIP](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/) (not mine!) then you don't need to mess with the $\mathop{\textbf{vec}}$ operator or Kronecker products, because it will do that for you. In CVX, the model is

```
cvx_begin
    variables A(m,n) lambda
    minimize(norm(A-A0,'fro'))
    subject to
        A >= 0
        A * x == lambda * x
cvx_end
```

EDIT: Another nice thing about using a framework like this is that if you decide you'd be interested in minimizing the spectral norm (i.e., the maximum singular value) of $A-A_0$ instead, you just change the objective to `norm(A-A0)`. You can even minimize the nuclear norm (i.e., the sum of the singular values) with `norm_nuc(A-A0)`!

For both of these alternatives, the problem must be recast as a [semidefinite program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming), and not in a straightforward manner; and it will be slower. But you can remain blissfully unaware of how the proverbial sausage is made, and let the framework do it for you. YALMIP can do all of these things as well.

Comment: Hi Michael, that's great, I tried in Matlab and it all worked. CVX seems really cool as well, thanks. A quick note to anyone else who wants to try this, I had to change 'Fro' to 'fro'.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, and the correction. I've edited the post.